# Erlang/ variable assignment

Tags: erlang

I looked into Erlang and was puzzled that reassignment of Variables, e.g. Counter is possible:

loop(Value,Counter)->
 io:format("~s,~n",[Value]),
 loop(Value,**Counter-1**).

I expected to see a purely functional language.
Or, should I shift my POV?

Cheers,

Tomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
loop(Value,Counter)-> io:format("~s,~n",[Value]), loop(Value,Counter-1).
```

In the above function definition, the name of the function itself appears on the right hand side of the definition, and is used with the same arity. We call this type of definition a recursive definition. Each recursive call will define a value called `Counter` which is only visible within the current recursion level. In other words, the number corresponding to the evaluation of the expression `Counter - 1` will be bound to a *new* `Counter` variable, unrelated scope-wise to the one used in the expression.

However, this type of recursive function call is called *tail-recursive*. It's a specific type of call which carries the property of being optimizable to a real loop. The end result is  that the memory cell for `Counter` used by the function will be updated with the new value and used in the recursive call, rather than allocated again for that new `Counter` value<sup>(1)</sup>. This allow potentially infinite recursion schemes.

---

Regarding the notion of functional language, it is difficult to answer that without establishing first a proper definition of what constitute a functional language, and what purely functional means.

In my book, an functional language is a language based of lambda calculus concepts: function abstraction and application, higher order functions: this is also called functions as first class citizen of the language. Erlang definitely fits that model. A pure FL would probably be one not supporting the other main paradigm of programmation, namely imperative (variable mutability). <s>Again Erlang matches that very definition. If you have different definitions, then Erlang's situation might be different.</s>

Pascal pointed out in the comments section that there's a facility in Erlang which doesn't follow the pure functional language paradigm:
[Process dictionaries](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced.html). Indeed it is possible to set values in that structure, and as noted:

> Note that using the Process Dictionary:
>
> - *Destroys referencial transparency*
> - Makes debugging difficult
> - Survives Catch/Throw

(emphasis mine).

Hence, Erlang isn't strictly pure.

---

<sub>(1) tail recursion isn't the only way to get that optimization in place: see http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. you set my POV in the right perspective. much appreciated :)))

Comment: No problem: the matrix can be misleading sometimes when setting a project up (^-^)

Comment: I took the liberty to update my answer with my understanding of what a functional language is. Please let me know if this isn't correct for you, and perhaps update your question to reflect your view of that idea.

Comment: In the definition of pure functional language we can include the lack of side effect. For this last point there is a known exception in Erlang: the process dictionary. This is very convenient for example to evaluate pseudo random values without passing the current seed at each function call, but generally it is not recommended to use it.

Comment: @Pascal thank you for your input, I was not aware of that point, I should probably include that in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no reassignment in your example - `Counter-1` is a new value which is not assigned to any existing variable.
2. Erlang isn't a pure functional language.

Comment: Could you elaborate on #2? (A counter example would be fine).

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271417/is-erlang-really-a-functional-language

Comment: Well, it is argued there that erlang is functional, but may not be pure, because of multithreading? That isn't really an issue for me. Haskell is said to be pure because it doesn't support mutability. It also support multithreading and encapsulate side effects in IO values. Also, what is a side effect free language? If it is about immutability, then  erlang fits the bill. If it is about not supporting any form of IO, I don't think such language exists.